# Entender el proceso del codigo

Tags: c, funciones, while

estoy tratando de realizar un ejercicio en el cual se basa en entender el proceso que esta realizando la siguiente funcion, el problema es que no entiendo absolutamente nada.

Si pueden ayudarme se lo agradeceria, un saludo.

````
void    ft_print_comb(void)
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    a = '0';
    while (a <= '7')
    {   
        b = a + 1;
        while (b <= '8')
        {   
            c = b + 1;
            while (c <= '9')
            {
                write (1, &a, 1);
                write (1, &b, 1);
                write (1, &c, 1);
                if (!(a == '7' && b == '8' && c == '9'))
                    write (1, ", ", 2);
                c++;
            }
            b++;
        }
        a++;
    }
}```
````

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: "...no entiendo absolutamente nada" ¿Absolutamente nada? ¿no sabes lo que significa por ejemplo `int a`? ¿O `a='0'`? ¿O no sabes qué hace un `while ( a<='7')`? ¿O lo que hace un `a++`? Si ya sabes algo de esto, entonces lo que no entiendes es otra cosa. ¿Puedes entonces ser más específico sobre qué es lo que no entiendes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El programa usa varias técnicas bastante confusas, como la de declarar una variable tipo `int` pero luego en cambio asignarle un char (`'0'`, `'1'`, etc), y usar aritmética sobre esos caracteres (`a++`, `b++`, etc)

La razón de hacerlo así es que luego (por razones que se escapan a mi comprensión) usa `write()` en lugar de `printf()` para imprimirlos en pantalla. Pero dejemos ese detalle para el final y vayamos por partes.

### ¿Qué hace el programa?

Escribe una serie de números de tres cifras separados por comas, en una sola línea. No escribe *todos* los números entre 000 y 999 como dijiste en un comentario, pues la segunda cifra siempre comienza siendo uno más que la primera, y la tercera uno más que la segunda. Es decir, el primer número volcado sería el `012`, y va incrementando la última cifra. Cuando ésta llega a `9`, se incrementa la penúltima (pasa a ser 2) y la última empieza siendo uno más que ésta (o sea, empieza siendo 3) por lo que tras el `019` va el `023`, y así sucesivamente.

La segunda "se para" al llegar a 8 en vez de 9 por lo que tras el `089` toca incrementar la primera cifra (que pasa a 1) y la segunda se reinicia en uno más que la primera (2) y la tercera en uno más que la segunda (3), así que tras el `089` saldría el `123`.

Como ves, no salen todos los números. No sé si esto es así a propósito o por un error de diseño y el objetivo era que salieran todos.

### ¿Cómo lo hace?

Bucles dentro de bucles. El bucle más interno se repite hasta que la condición del `while` deja de ser cierta, y entonces se sale de ese bucle interno, y se vuelve al bucle en el cual estaba encerrado, que inicia una nueva iteración. Por cada iteración de ese bucle "padre", es necesario volver a realizar todas las iteraciones que toquen del bucle "hijo".

Por ejemplo, imagina que el bucle más externo de todos ya se ha ejecutado tres veces y por tanto `a` vale `'2'`. El bucle del medio ya se ha ejecutado también algunas veces y `b` vale `'5'`. Iteramos una vez más por este bucle intermedio:

```
        while (b <= '8')
        {   
            c = b + 1;
            while (c <= '9')
            {
                write (1, &a, 1); write (1, &b, 1); write (1, &c, 1);
                if (!(a == '7' && b == '8' && c == '9'))
                    write (1, ", ", 2);
                c++;
            }
            b++;
```

Ya que (estoy suponiendo) `b` vale `'5'`, se cumple que `b<='8'` por lo que se entra al bucle y se hace `c=b+1`. Esta suma es un poco rara, porque estás sumando 1 (un entero) al carácter `'5'` (que no es un entero). Ocurre que todos los caracteres se almacenan en realidad como enteros, por lo que en realidad estás sumando 1 al *código ascii* del carácter `'5'`, y te sale el código ascii del carácter `'6'`. Ese es el valor inicial de `c`.

Ahora hay que iterar mientras `c<='9'`, y para cada iteración imprimir a, b, c seguidos (eso hace el write, ya lo explicaré al final) y luego una coma. Así que el bucle interno se repetirá para c igual a `'6'`,  `'7'`, `'8'` y `'9'` (pues el siguiente `'8'` ya sería mayor que `'7'` por lo que se sale del bucle interno. Ese bucle interno por tanto mostrará "256, 257, 258, 259" y terminará.

Entonces se incrementa `b` (que pasa a valer `'6'`) y se vuelve al `while(b<='7')`. Como de nuevo es cierto, se itera otra vez, y ahora se inicializa `c` con el valor `7` y se entra al bucle interno que en esta ocasión se ejecutará con `c` desde '7' hasta '9' e imprimirá "267, 268, 269, "

Se acaba el bucle interno, se incrementa `b` (que pasa a valer '7') y se ejecuta de nuevo el bucle interno, esta vez con la `c` variando entre '8' y '9'  y por tanto imprimirá "278, 279, "

Se acaba el bucle interno, se incrementa `b` (que pasa a valer '8') y como ya no se cumple lo de `b<='7'` se termina el bucle en `b`, y se sale del mismo. Entonces se incrementaría `a` (pasará a '3') y *se vuelve al bucle en `b`* sólo que esta vez con `b` empezando en 4, por lo que el bucle en `c` variará desde '5' hasta '9', imprimiendo "345, 346, 347, 348, 349, " etc. Creo que ya se ve el patrón.

### Qué hace el `write()`

`write()` es una función de bajo nivel para enviar bytes a flujos de salida (normalmente ficheros). El primer parámetro es un entero que representa al flujo al cual queremos enviar los bytes. En tu caso se usa `1`, que es un número de flujo especial que representa a la **salida estándar**. Por tanto en lugar de a fichero, emitirá los bytes por la salida estándar (pantalla).

El segundo parámetro es una dirección de memoria de donde debe tomar los bytes a enviar. Por eso hay que pasarle `&a` o `&b` (pues el operador `&` te devuelve la dirección de memoria en que se halla una variable).

El tercer parámetro es cuántos bytes queremos enviar. En tu caso usas 1 porque un dígito como '3'  es lo que ocupa. El código ascii de ese dígito es lo que se estaría enviando.

Al enviar la coma en cambio se pone `write(1, ", ", 2)` y este 2 es porque en este caso se envían dos bytes (la coma y el espacio). Y han de delimitarse por comillas dobles para que sean una *cadena* y no un solo carácter.

### Una versión más "normal"

Si en vez de `write()` usamos `printf()` entonces podemos trabajar con enteros en vez de caracteres, lo que hace el programa algo más legible. También podemos cambiar los `while` por `for`, que nos da algo más compacto, y quedaría así:

```
void ft_print_comb2(void) {
  int a, b, c;
  for (a=0; a<=7; a++) 
    for (b=a+1; b<=8; b++) 
      for (c=b+1; c<=9; c++)
        printf("%d%d%d, ", a, b, c);
}
```

(bueno, he hecho un poco de trampa y para simplificar aún más he impreso la coma al final de todos los números, incluido el último, y no como tu programa original que omitía la coma tras el último)

La salida es:

```
012, 013, 014, 015, 016, 017, 018, 019, 023, 024, 025, 026, 027, 028, 029, 
034, 035, 036, 037, 038, 039, 045, 046, 047, 048, 049, 056, 057, 058, 059, 
067, 068, 069, 078, 079, 089, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 134, 135, 
136, 137, 138, 139, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 156, 157, 158, 159, 167, 168, 
169, 178, 179, 189, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 
256, 257, 258, 259, 267, 268, 269, 278, 279, 289, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 
356, 357, 358, 359, 367, 368, 369, 378, 379, 389, 456, 457, 458, 459, 467, 
468, 469, 478, 479, 489, 567, 568, 569, 578, 579, 589, 678, 679, 689, 789,
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, lo entendi perfectamente. La razon por la cual usamos write y while es por obligacion en el bootcamp en el que estoy. Un abrazo!

Answer (score 1):

En base a esta pregunta supongo que no tienes mucha experiencia en la programación.

Te explico paso a paso:

```
int a;
int b;
int c;
```

Aquí se hacen las declaraciones de las variables, con esto le estas diciendo al programa que datos vas a manejar, en este caso al ser int (Integer) significa que serán números enteros.

```
 a = '0';
```

Simplemente es darle un valor a la variable 'a', en este caso a vale 0.

```
 while (a <= '7')
```

Esto es un bucle, mientras se cumpla la condición que hay dentro, es decir mientras que a sea menor o igual que 7, el código se repetirá las veces que haga falta hasta que se cumpla la condición.

```
 b = a + 1;
 while (b <= '8')
```

Aquí igual que antes se le da un valor a 'b' el cual es el valor actual de 'a' (el cual ahora es 0) mas 1, es decir 'b' es igual a 1. Y por otro lado se abre un bucle nuevo que se ejecutara mientras que 'b' sea menor o igual que 8.

```
 c = b + 1;
        while (c <= '9')
```

Esto es lo mismo que arriba.

```
 write (1, &a, 1);
 write (1, &b, 1);
 write (1, &c, 1);
```

Esta función de C es simplemente escribir el valor de a, b y c. Si quieres mas información la puedes encontrar [aquí](https://baulderasec.wordpress.com/programacion/programacion-con-linux/3-trabajando-con-los-archivos/acceso-de-bajo-nivel-a-archivos/write/).

```
if (!(a == '7' && b == '8' && c == '9'))
```

Esto es una condición a secas, sin bucle, la exclamación significa lo contrario, es decir si el resultado de la condición seria true con la exclamación se quedaría en false. Dentro de la condición se mira si el valor a es igual a 7, si 'b' es igual a 8 y si 'c' es igual a 9. Mientras que no se cumplan estas tres condiciones se ejecutara lo siguiente:

```
write (1, ", ", 2);
```

Esto es escribir una coma y un espacio en la consola.

Por ultimo las sentencias:

```
c++; b++; a++;
```

Estas sentencias suman 1 a la variable asignada, es decir, c++ hará que la variable c la cual era 2 se le sume 1, es decir se quedaría en 3.

Espero que hayas entendido un poco mas el código. Happy coding! :)

Comment: Hola, perdona, de la frustracion no me enfoque en explicarme lo suficiente. Principalmente te agradezco enormemente le ayuda, los conocimientos que tenia los he reforzado con tu explicacion.

Comment: La razon por la cual utilizamos write o while, es porque estoy en un bootcamp donde nos obligan a utilizar unicamente esas funciones. El problema que creo que tengo, es que no entiendo el proceso que hace un while dentro de un while dentro de otro while. Y tambien no entiendo la logica del programa, unicamente se que se trata de un ejercicio donde se pinta todos los numeros del 1 al 999 sin repetirse ni uno.

Comment: Un `while` no cambia su lógica independientemente de dónde esté situado en tu programa. Es un bucle que se repite constantemente hasta que se deje de cumplir la condición que tiene como argumento. ¿Qué pasa si tienes 2 `while` uno dentro de otro? Pues que se empieza ejecutando el primero, cuando se encuentra el segundo éste se ejecuta. Cuando la condición del segundo no se cumple sale, y se termina de ejecutar el primero y vuelve a ejecutarse el primero (si la condición se cumple), y en este caso podría volver a ejecutarse el segundo (si la condición de éste se cumple) y así sucesivamente.